# Defining Prediction Interval (exercise 10 from the chapter 13 of All of Statistics)

Tags: regression, prediction-interval

I am struggling with the exercise 10 on the prediction interval from the Wassermann's "All of Statistics" book.

[image]

In a) the aim is to show that
$$ P(-2 < N(0, 1+\frac{\sigma^2}{s^2}) < 2) \neq 0.95 \\ $$

So, I want to show that the following equality is false.
$$ P(-\frac{2}{1+\frac{\sigma^2}{s^2}} < N(0, 1) < \frac{2}{1+\frac{\sigma^2}{s^2}}) = 0.95\\ $$

But it is true if
$$ \frac{2}{1+\frac{\sigma^2}{s^2}} = 1.96 \\
\sigma^2 = 0.0204*s^2
$$
What I don't understand?

Additionally, in b) I am not sure why $Y_{*}$ is equal to parameter $\theta$ plus a random variable (why not only $\theta$?). And I don't know how to prove the last inequality.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: the *only* fact you need to know (apart from having a basic understanding of Normal distributions) is that $\sigma^2/s^2 \gt 0.$  Even better: $E[\sigma^2/s^2] \gt 1.$